# GCC inline assembly error: no such instruction: `stosd'

Tags: visual-c++, gcc, assembly, inline-assembly

Oh man, I've got yet another error while compiling the following inline assembly code (with **-fasm-blocks**) under **GCC**:

```
_asm
{
    mov ecx, esi
    shr ecx, 2
    rep stosd
};
```

**GCC** understands other **stos** instructions, why won't it accept **stosd**???

Comment: which version of the compiler are you using?

Comment: Apple GCC 4.2.1, the error is no such instruction: `stosd'...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

seeing as your using intel syntax, just go for the explicit version of the `STOS` command: `REP STOS DWORD PTR:[EDI]`.

and iirc under gcc, `stosd` is called `stosl`.

Comment: please share the complete list of replacements, or the URL where to see that

Answer (score 1):

Another way to fix this is to tell gcc to use intel assembly syntax with "-masm=intel".